# Binary search loop is not breaking when the search element input is not prsenting in the sorted array

Tags: c, binary-search

I am implementing the binary search in C as below, but when I'm passing the element which is not available in the sorted array, the code is enter into infinite loop since the midelement is repetitively calculating the same value (midelement is 4, and then start index becomes 5 (elementtofind > InputArray[midelement]), end index is 4, hence again returns the mid element as 4) after the 9th iteration of the loop, can anyone find how could I improve this logic.

```
#define MAX_NUM_INPUT     (358U)
uint16 InputArray[MAX_NUM_INPUT] = {0x0103, 0x0104, 0x0109, 0x010A, 0x0133, 0x0180, 0x181, 0x183,.....upto 358 elements};

int main()
{
    boolean elmntFound = 0;
    uint16 elmntTofnd = 0x0134;
    elmntFound = SearchPassedElement(0, MAX_NUM_INPUT, elmntTofnd);
    if(elmntFound == 0)
    {
        printf("elementfound");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("elementNOTfound");
    }
}
static boolean SearchPassedElement (uint16 FrstElmntIdx,uint16 LstElmntIdx, uint16 ElmntToFind)
{
  boolean ReturnValue = 1;
  uint16 startIdx = FrstElmntIdx;
  uint16 endIdx = LstElmntIdx;
  uint16 loc_midElmntIdx;
  boolean OperationStatus = FALSE;
  
    if(LstElmntIdx >= FrstElmntIdx)
    {
        while (OperationStatus == FALSE)
        {
            loc_midElmntIdx = (startIdx + endIdx) / 2U ;
            if (ElmntToFind == InputArray[loc_midElmntIdx])
            {
                OperationStatus = TRUE;
                ReturnValue   = 0 ; 
            }
            else if (ElmntToFind > InputArray[loc_midElmntIdx])
            {
                /* if entire array was already checked*/
                if (startIdx == endIdx) 
                {  
                    OperationStatus = TRUE;
                    ReturnValue   = 1 ; 
                }
                else /* othewise, */
                {
                    startIdx = loc_midElmntIdx + 1U;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* if entire array was already checked*/
                if (startIdx == endIdx) 
                {  
                    OperationStatus = TRUE;
                    ReturnValue   = 1 ; 
                }
                else /* othewise, */
                {
                    endIdx = loc_midElmIdx - 1U ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        loopCntr = 0;
        /* Incorrect input arguments */
        ReturnValue = 1;
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

I have found one logic as if the midelemnt is returned with same value for more than 3 times the lop shall be breaked, and evaluating the same.

```
static boolean SearchPassedElement (uint16 FrstElmntIdx,uint16 LstElmntIdx, uint16 ElmntToFind)
{
    boolean ReturnValue = 1;
    uint16 startIdx = FrstElmntIdx;
    uint16 endIdx = LstElmntIdx;
    uint16 loc_midElmntIdx;
    boolean OperationStatus = FALSE;
    uint16 prev_loc_midElmIdx = 0;
    uint16 is_midElmIdxSame_count = 0;
  
    if(LstElmntIdx >= FrstElmntIdx)
    {
        while (OperationStatus == FALSE)
        {
            loc_midElmntIdx = (startIdx + endIdx) / 2U ;
            if (ElmntToFind == InputArray[loc_midElmntIdx])
            {
                OperationStatus = TRUE;
                ReturnValue   = 0 ; 
            }
            else if (ElmntToFind > InputArray[loc_midElmntIdx])
            {
                /* if entire array was already checked*/
                if (startIdx == endIdx) 
                {  
                    OperationStatus = TRUE;
                    ReturnValue   = 1 ; 
                }
                else /* othewise, */
                {
                    startIdx = loc_midElmntIdx + 1U;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* if entire array was already checked*/
                if (startIdx == endIdx) 
                {  
                    OperationStatus = TRUE;
                    ReturnValue   = 1 ; 
                }
                else /* othewise, */
                {
                    endIdx = loc_midElmIdx - 1U ;
                }
            }
            if(prev_loc_midElmIdx != loc_midElmIdx)
            {
                prev_loc_midElmIdx = loc_midElmIdx;
            }
            else
            {
                is_midElmIdxSame_count++;
                /*as the divisor is 2 the same value can't return more that 2 times, hence if the same value is return more than
                * 2 times the loop should be braked
                */
                if(is_midElmIdxSame_count == 3)
                {
                    elmntNotFnd = 3;
                    /* Stop operation and return failure*/
                    OperationStatus = TRUE;
                    ReturnValue   = 1 ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        loopCntr = 0;
        /* Incorrect input arguments */
        ReturnValue = 1;
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: `boolean` is not a standard C type. Include `<stdbool.h>` and use the standard `bool` type, together with `true` and `false`.

Comment: As for the problem itself, have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: ```int16_t``` is defined in ```stdint.h```, but where is ```uint16``` defined?

Comment: They are all defined in the horrid land of C90 coding conventions. Because why program like it's the 21st century.

Comment: In any case, someone would have already debugged it for you if you would have provided a [mcve].

Comment: Hello All, after the debugging I found the mid element is return the same values from the 9th iteration and moreover the code I have posted here is only the function which needs some guidance from the forum members, thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think your code is unnecessarily very complicated. It seems like you are writing C in another language.

Comment: Hi @Zakk my objective is to find the given number is preset in an array which size is more than 300 bytes, if it is present then it should returns success, if it is not present it returns failure, hence I tried binary search algorithm, if you can give your comments related to what you are pointing out as unnecessary codes which would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such type called `boolean` in C. You have to `#include <stdbool.h>` to use the `bool` type. The same thing for `uint16`, you have to `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint16_t`.

And your code is very complicated. You needlessly use a lot of variables to get one simple thing done.

Here is a more compact version:

```
bool binary_search(size_t start, size_t end, const uint16_t elem, const uint16_t array[])
{
    while (start < end) {
        size_t middle = (start + end) / 2;
        
        if (elem == array[middle])
            return true;
        if (elem < array[middle])
            end = middle;
        else
            start = middle + 1;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It returns `true` if the element is found, `false` otherwise.

Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint16_t array[] = {1U, 2U, 3U, 4U, 5U, 6U, 7U, 8U, 9U, 10U};
    const size_t size = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
    const uint16_t elem = 10U;
    
    printf("%s\n", binary_search(0, size, elem, array) ? "Found" : "Not found");
}
```

```
Found
```

---

Few things to note:

- `size_t` is the appropriate type for indexing arrays.
- Use `const` (i.e. read-only) when you don't modify your variables.
- Don't write C in Pascal style.